# Import of data from ODS

Tags: bugs, import, spreadsheets

With

```
SetDirectory["~/Downloads"];
ifile = "test.xls";
TimeConstrained[idata = Import[ifile, {"Data", 1}], 5];
```

I can achieve the desired result of importing the first page of the spreadsheet in under 5 seconds.

When the same data are reformatted (Excel "Save As ...") to ODS format

```
SetDirectory["~/Downloads"];
Clear[idata];
ifile = "test.ods";
TimeConstrained[idata = Import[ifile, {"Data", 1}], 60];
```

times out.

Is ODS Import[] broken? Does anybody else have this issue?

Comment: But ... how long does it take if you don't time constraint it?

Comment: @belisarius: Good question.  I'm cognisant that things take time.  However, longer than 10 minutes to read a 500 kb file is stretching the friendship. At 15 minutes, I'm still waiting.

Answer (score 4):

I reported this to Wolfram Research and it has been classiefied as a bug.

No word on a fix.

Comment: Can you add the issue-tracking number?

Comment: My tracking number is 2558090

Comment: Has this been fixed? I am seeing huge cpu usage with 11.1.0 on LInux without any results, I have to abort in the end.

Comment: @leosenko: I just tried this on 11.2.0. For a very simple data set, I get timings of 0.016, 0.024 & 0.06 for data in xlsx, xls and ods formats respectively suggesting that things may be fixed. How large is your file?

Comment: @leosenko: However when I try to Import[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {64, 64}]], csv, xls, and xlsx are (essentially) instantaneous. ODS times out, so things may not be fixed.